# Multi-purpose Stored Procedure: How to know which statement is stable?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

In this [blog post](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/high-performance-procedures/) Kimberly L. Tripp describes the best way to create a multi-purpose stored procedure. The best way as she mentions is to use `option(recompile)` when the statement is unstable so that the execution plan won't be put in cache and `sp_executesql` when we know that the statement is stable and that depends of the type of column passed to the statement.

**My question is how would we know if a statement is stable based on the column?**

1) If my statement is stable when I specify a column would it be stable when I specify that column along other columns?

2) If a column is highly selective (their values are different, we can know that from the density vector with a low value of AllDensity colmun) does it mean automatically that the statement which have this column is stable?

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually a simple question to answer. There are many aspects that affect plan stability, what gets cached, and how to avoid unnecessary recompilation. The biggest issue in what you're describing is the way that cardinality estimates vary, based upon statistics. For example, if I want to retrieve customers with names like A%, that might be entirely different to customers with names like D%, and very different to even AB%. The parameter value can have a major impact on determining what the appropriate plan is. This affects all the parameters. So what you're trying to assess if if different parameter values would lead to wildly differing plans.

For detailed coverage of how this works, I wrote an MSDN whitepaper back in 2012 and while that's 8 years ago, nothing about what you're asking about has changed significantly. You'll find it here: https://blog.greglow.com/2013/03/17/whitepaper-plan-caching-and-recompilations-in-sql-server-2012/

I'm hoping to get a chance this year to update it to the latest versions.